# How to increase speed in Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using `Picasso` to load images, scale and set to `listview` item. There is my code:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(builder.toString())
                            .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                            .into(new Target() {
                                @Override
                                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                    int width = Double.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth() * 0.75).intValue();
                                    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                                    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                                }
                    });
```

The problem appears when I made `new Target()` object in the `.into()` method, before that the speed of loaded images were very fast. 
I thought what exactly slowed down my work and how to correct it? Is scale memory-expensive or this is because of `new Target()` implementation at all?

Who faced with this problem? How to solve that?

Comment: You must scale the images on the server side, for example creating thumbnails, and then download these thumbnails with Picasso.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fresco for image loading..even facebook using same and for scaling you can use android:scaleType.its very usefull
Read about Fresco
http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the Glide Library An image loading and caching library for Android focused on smooth scrolling.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Picasso is also a good for cashing or U can use LRU cache.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't seeing slowness. That `Target` will probably never be called.

Picasso only holds a WeakReference to a `Target`. You need to hold your own reference to that `Target`, or else it will be cleared and gc'd before it can be loaded into.