# Android Picasso Recyclerview Image downloading slow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, picasso, android-lazyloading

I have endless recyclerview that almost mimics Instagram list/feeds. Where Image is loading into full screen width Imageview. I am using Picasso to load images. Here is my code:

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

Context context;

private Contract contract;

List<Feed> feeds;

static final int ITEM_TYPE_HEADER = 0;

static final int ITEM_TYPE_LOAD_MORE = 1;

static final int ITEM_TYPE_DESIGN = 2;

public HomeAdapter(Context context, List<Feed> feeds) {
    this.context = context;
    this.feeds = feeds;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View row;
    if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_HEADER) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_home_header, parent, false);
        return new HeaderHolder(row);
    } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_LOAD_MORE) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_load_more, parent, false);
        return new LoadMoreHolder(row);
    } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_DESIGN) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_feed_home, parent, false);
        return new DesignItemHolder(row);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Feed feed = feeds.get(position);
    if (holder instanceof HeaderHolder) {
        HeaderHolder headerHolder = (HeaderHolder) holder;
        Header header = (Header) feed;
        headerHolder.tvTitle.setText(header.getTitle());
        headerHolder.tvDescription.setText(header.getDescription());

    } else if (holder instanceof LoadMoreHolder) {
        LoadMoreHolder loadMoreHolder = (LoadMoreHolder) holder;
        LoadMore loadMore = (LoadMore) feed;
        if(loadMore.getType() == LOAD_MORE_TYPE_PROGRESS) {
            loadMoreHolder.pbLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadMoreHolder.rlMessageRetry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            loadMoreHolder.pbLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadMoreHolder.rlMessageRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(StringUtils.isValid(loadMore.getTitle())) {
                loadMoreHolder.tvTitle.setText(loadMore.getTitle());
                loadMoreHolder.tvTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else
                loadMoreHolder.tvTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(StringUtils.isValid(loadMore.getDescription())) {
                loadMoreHolder.tvDescription.setText(loadMore.getDescription());
                loadMoreHolder.tvDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else
                loadMoreHolder.tvDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        loadMoreHolder.btnRetry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onRetryLoadMoreClick();
            }
        });

    } else if (holder instanceof DesignItemHolder) {
        final DesignItemHolder designItemHolder = (DesignItemHolder) holder;
        final DesignFeed designFeed = (DesignFeed) feed;
        String title = getFeedTitle(designFeed.getDesignCategory().getTitle(), designFeed.getEvent().getTitle());
        designItemHolder.tvCategory.setText(StringUtils.toUpperCaseSentence(designFeed.getDesignCategory().getTitle()));
        designItemHolder.tvDate.setText(DateTimeUtils.formatTime(designFeed.getDate()));
        designItemHolder.tvTitle.setText(StringUtils.toUpperCaseSentence(title));
        designItemHolder.tvBrand.setText(getBrandTitle(designFeed.getBrand().getTitle()));

        if(StringUtils.isValid(designFeed.getShopLink())) {
            designItemHolder.tvShop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(StringUtils.isValid(designFeed.getPrice())) {
                designItemHolder.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                designItemHolder.tvPrice.setText(designFeed.getPrice() + " PKR");
            } else
                designItemHolder.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            designItemHolder.tvShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(contract != null)
                        contract.onOpenShopLink(designFeed.getShopLink());
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            designItemHolder.tvPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            designItemHolder.tvShop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        showFeedImage(designFeed, designItemHolder.ivThumbnail, designItemHolder.progressBar);

        Picasso.get()
                .load(designFeed.getDesignCategory().getThumbnail())
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGreyLight)))
                .into(designItemHolder.ivCategory);

        designItemHolder.ivThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onDesignFeedClick(designFeed);
            }
        });

        designItemHolder.tvCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onDesignCategoryClick(designFeed.getDesignCategory());
            }
        });

        designItemHolder.ivCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onDesignCategoryClick(designFeed.getDesignCategory());
            }
        });

        designItemHolder.tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onDesignCategoryClick(designFeed.getDesignCategory());
            }
        });

        designItemHolder.tvBrand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onBrandClick(designFeed.getBrand());
            }
        });

        designItemHolder.ibFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onFavouriteClick(designFeed);
            }
        });

        designItemHolder.ibShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onShareClick(designFeed);
            }
        });

        designItemHolder.ibDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contract != null)
                    contract.onDownloadClick(designFeed);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void showFeedImage(final DesignFeed designFeed, final ImageView ivThumbnail, final ProgressBar progressBar) {
    Picasso.get()
            .load(designFeed.getThumbnail())
            .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGreyLight)))
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .into(ivThumbnail, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    //Try again online if cache failed
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(designFeed.getThumbnail())
                            .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGreyLight)))
                            .into(ivThumbnail, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Exception e) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Feed feed = feeds.get(position);
    if (feed instanceof Header)
        return ITEM_TYPE_HEADER;
    else if (feed instanceof LoadMore)
        return ITEM_TYPE_LOAD_MORE;
    else if (feed instanceof DesignFeed)
        return ITEM_TYPE_DESIGN;
    else
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feeds.size();
}

public void insertFeedAtStart(Feed feed) {
    feeds.add(0, feed);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void updateFeeds(ArrayList<Feed> mFeeds) {
    feeds.addAll(mFeeds);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addLoadMoreItem(Feed loadMoreFeed) {
    feeds.add(loadMoreFeed);
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
}

public void removeItem(int index) {
    feeds.remove(index);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class DesignItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle, tvCategory, tvBrand, tvDate, tvPrice, tvShop;
    ImageView ivCategory, ivThumbnail;
    ImageButton ibFavourite, ibShare, ibDownload;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    DesignItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
        tvBrand = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvBrand);
        tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        ivCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCategory);
        ivThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnail);
        tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        tvShop = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvShop);
        ibFavourite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibFavourite);
        ibShare = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibShare);
        ibDownload = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibDownload);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}

private class HeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle, tvDescription;
    HeaderHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    }
}

private class LoadMoreHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ProgressBar pbLoadMore;
    RelativeLayout rlMessageRetry;
    TextView tvTitle, tvDescription;
    AppCompatButton btnRetry;

    LoadMoreHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        pbLoadMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pbLoadMore);
        rlMessageRetry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlMessageRetry);
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        btnRetry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnRetry);
    }
}

public void setContract(Contract contract) {
    this.contract = contract;
}

public interface Contract {

    void onDesignCategoryClick(DesignCategory designCategory);

    void onDesignFeedClick(DesignFeed designCategory);

    void onBrandClick(Brand brand);

    void onRetryLoadMoreClick();

    void onShopClick(String shopLink);

    void onFavouriteClick(DesignFeed designFeed);

    void onShareClick(DesignFeed designFeed);

    void onDownloadClick(DesignFeed designFeed);

    void onOpenShopLink(String shopLink);
}
```

}

Average image size is 80-100 kbs. But image download time is too slow. It almost takes 3-4 seconds to download an image. On the other hand when images are loading from cache it obviously loads an image in no time. I get 15 items from server to load into recyclerview which means 15 images would be downloading in parallel. But still it is quite slow as compared to Instagram or Facebook feeds.

Can anyone guide me about the correct technique to make it as fast as possible, so that when user scrolls down the list images should be already loaded instead him waiting for image to load?

Comment: 2 Questions: `1)` What type of upload / download speeds are you getting with your current internet connection? and `2)` If you write a simple get request to ping the server returning these images (just use one of your URLs from the app), or use something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), what is the response time in milliseconds?

Comment: @Silmarilos if I open download link on browser it downloads in milliseconds, images are deployed on aws s3 bucket, And Internet connection speed is quite fast If i use any other app like Facebook its images are loading fast

Comment: use universal image loader it is fast compare to picasso. Also try using okhttp downloader along with picasso

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have been using the lib for a long time without any networking issue. I tried to analyze the code and found out followings:

1. The problem could be the transformation Since lib first transforms incoming image then display, Please refer this part

   Picasso.get()

   ```
       .load(designFeed.getDesignCategory().getThumbnail())
       .transform(new CircleTransform())
       .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
        R.color.colorGreyLight)))
       .into(designItemHolder.ivCategory);
   ```

Advice: if you are trying to show image in circular view. Then use CircularImageView, do not free I/O.

- Check the performance with other a little powerful devices than yours

**EDIT**

- Check your phone for network usage, which app is consuming, how much megabytes, Since some applications silently use your network in the background
- Why it is fast in your browser? Because your browser is not doing any extra operation on the image

Answer (score 0):

If your images are too large, then it may take some time. so 15 image with 100kb size is almost 1.5 Mb to load

If you use `fit()` or `resize()` that should fix your issue. I currently load hundreds of jpg files that are very large into a single `GridLayout` and have no problems.

**edit**

it might be a internet issue and **Picasso** has no control over the server fulfilling the network request or the internet connection itself. Using a service like Thumbor might help: https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor

Comment: I have already tried fit(), resize() and centerInside() etc still it takes time, As I have mentioned that Download takes time, resizing comes after download once images are downloaded then it does not take time to load from cache

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can your this code flow:

> 1. Create a Feeds class (POJO or Model) with Singleton ability with a constructor,
> 2. Start filling the Feeds class in Asynchronous Background Task when your app starts to get some extra time, 
>      `Feeds feed_ins = Feeds.getInstance(SomeData)`
> 3. In the Feeds class get the bitmap from Picasso by calling a defined method from the constructor and save it to a list, `List<Bitmap> imageBitmaps = new ArrayList<>()`
> 4. In the Feeds class create a method that returns the particular bitmap on call with the poitsion, `getImageBitmap(int position){ return imageBitmaps.get(position) }`
> 5. At HomeAdapter get Feeds class instance, `Feeds feed_ins = Feeds.getInstance();`
> 6. Now at the HomeAdapter class use the Feeds class singleton to directly fetch the bitmap,
>      `ivThumbnail.setImageBitmap(feed_ins.getImageBitmap(int position))`

This shall solve you load time problem by the preloading of images.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put your holder classes `static`. Every `findViewById` has a real cost in performance. As you can see your class has a lot of `findViewById`. In other hand I suggest to take a look the difference between Picasso and Glide, there are differences in how they manage images.

> When I tried to download images from the URL, Picasso was quite fast in loading the image from the internet than Glide. Maybe because after downloading the image, Picasso directly pushes the full-size image to the memory; while Glide resizes the image as per the dimension of the ImageView.

https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d

Answer (score 0):

Please check these answers that could be useful for you.

[Load large images with Picasso and custom Transform object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741267/9169701)

[How to increase speed in Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35149252/9169701)

[How to make Picasso load images faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49544968/9169701)

You can improve this code:

```
Picasso.get()
        .load(designFeed.getDesignCategory().getThumbnail())
        .transform(new CircleTransform())
        .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGreyLight)))
        .into(designItemHolder.ivCategory);
```

New placeholder and transformation are created every `onBindViewHolder` calling. So you can create local variables for this case. Something like this..

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

Context context;
private final CircleTransform circleTransform;
private final ColorDrawable placeholderDrawable;

.
.
.

public HomeAdapter(Context context, List<Feed> feeds) {
    this.context = context;
    this.feeds = feeds;
    this.circleTransform = new CircleTransform();
    this.placeholderDrawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGreyLight))
}
```

Usage:

```
Picasso.get()
        .load(designFeed.getDesignCategory().getThumbnail())
        .transform(circleTransform)
        .placeholder(placeholderDrawable)
        .into(designItemHolder.ivCategory);
```

I also would recommend you take a look on the [rguzman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56402148/9169701). This tweak improve performance too.